# Bitbucket Authentication failed on pushing existing project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3, bitbucket

This is the error on my terminal:

```
Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed.git/'
```

This is what I did:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kboygitgit/sample_app.git
git push -u origin master
```

then it asked for my username and password

then the error showed up

```
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed.git/'
```

Comment: Are you on a new machine and if yes, did you add your public key in Bitbucket profile?

Comment: No I am not in a new machine , I cloned this repo and then tried to push this to my bitbucket profile

Comment: Please check if your access is read-only!

Comment: how do I do that can you please walkthrough me on this

Comment: Login to your Bitucket account, and click on the repository you are trying to push into, and in the overview section you will see something like this
Access level:
Admin (revoke)
OR maybe Readonly!

Comment: Put some bits in your bucket
Add some code or content and start bringing your ideas to life. Learn how
Get started the easy way
Creating a README or a .gitignore is a quick and easy way to get something into your repository.
Create a README Create a .gitignore
Get started with command line
 I have an existing project
 I'm starting from scratch

Comment: That is what I see on my overview , I did push my existing project on github which is fine but on bitbucket I cannot do it

Comment: See the top section of overview in [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/files/304578655/598940298/1/1400595347275/overview-readmecode-sidexpand.png) image

Comment: Oh mine is in Admin

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you might not have added your system's public key to bitbucket.

Comment: I did and if ever I forget to that step how do I do that?

Comment: Did this "git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kboygitgit/sample_app.git" actually work? Please do a "git remote -v" are post the results back here. Maybe you need to do a git remote add myrepo ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kboygitgit/sample_app.git
git push -u myrepo master

Comment: heroku https://git.heroku.com/kboysample.git (fetch)
heroku https://git.heroku.com/kboysample.git (push)
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kboygitgit/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/kboygitgit/sample_app.git (push)